# No such table exists

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to create more than one table in the database but the first table is only created successfully and the two others gives me errors i want to know how to make sure that the tables are created

```
04-18 17:20:45.343: E/AndroidRuntime(956): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: squares: , while compiling: SELECT _squareid, squarename, squarelatitude, squarelongitude FROM squares
```

here it is my code

```
public class Dbinfo {

    public static final String KEY_RAWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_RAWNAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_SQUAREID = "_squareid";
    public static final String KEY_SQUARENAME = "squarename";
    public static final String KEY_SQUARELATITUDE = "squarelatitude";
    public static final String KEY_SQUARELONGITUDE = "squarelongitude";
    private static final String KEY_STREETID = "streetid";
    private static final String KEY_STREETNAME = "streetname";
    private static final String KEY_STREETLATITUDE="streetlatitude";
    private static final String KEY_STREETLONGTIUDE="streetlongtiude";
    private static final String KEY_STREETCAPACITY = "streetcapacity";
    private static final String KEY_STREETFOREIGN = "streetforegin";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users_DB";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "users";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLESQUARES = "squares";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE_STREETS = "streets";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private dbusers ourhelper;
    private final Context ourcontext;
    private static SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

    private static class dbusers extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public dbusers(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_TABLE, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + "(" + KEY_RAWID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_RAWNAME
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                    + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT NOT NULL);");

            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLESQUARES + "("
                    + KEY_SQUAREID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_SQUARENAME + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SQUARELATITUDE
                    + "TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SQUARELONGITUDE
                    + "TEXT NOT NULL);");

            final String STREET = "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE_STREETS
                    + " (" + KEY_STREETID
                    + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + KEY_STREETNAME+
                    " TEXT NOT NULL"+KEY_STREETLATITUDE+"TEXT NOT NULL"+KEY_SQUARELONGITUDE
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_STREETCAPACITY
                    + " text not null, FOREIGN KEY (" + KEY_STREETFOREIGN
                    + ") REFERENCES " + DATABASE_TABLESQUARES + " ("
                    + KEY_SQUAREID + "));";
            db.execSQL(STREET);
```

Any help??

Comment: Looks like, you created one table, run the app, and then try to create another one. You should be properly handing the migrations. For a quick fix, uninstall the app, and run this exact same code.

Comment: delete your database (Settings > apps > .. delete data) and try again. onCreate is only called if the database did not exist before

Comment: See Luksprog's answer; also you will need to add commas and spaces to your streets table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put some spaces after your column names in your `sql` creation `String`(for the table `DATABASE_TABLESQUARES`):

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLESQUARES + "("
                    + KEY_SQUAREID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + KEY_SQUARENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SQUARELATITUDE
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + KEY_SQUARELONGITUDE
                    + " TEXT NOT NULL);");
```

After you make the above modifications you'll have to uninstall the app and re run it so the `onCreate` method of the `SQLiteOpenHelper` will be called again to initialize a database  according to the new sql `String`.
Also, as Sam's comment, also modify the sql creation `String` for the table `DATABASE_TABLE_STREETS` and add some commas between the column declaration(like you previously did for the other two tables) or will get in trouble again when you try to access that table.

Comment: add a space after the table name also

Comment: @achie: not necessary (at least for sqlite)

Comment: What do you mean by uninstalling the application?? do you mean closing the emulator and run it again?

Comment: If you modify that string like I did in my answer and then run the app, you'll get the same problems because the `onCreate` method(for the `SQLiteOpenHelper`) is called only once when the database is created(and will not be called unless the database is gone). I mean uninstall the application: Go to the phone/emulator `Settings`-> `Applications`-> find the app and uninstall it from there. Then run it again.

Answer (score 0):

first check your database with SQLite Browser.
If no table found then you have problem with creating table.check following code for create
table.

```
private static final String DATABASE_CREATE3 = "create table IF NOT EXISTS "
        + TABLE_EXAM + "( " + COLUMN_EXAM_ID
        + " integer primary key autoincrement, " 
        + COLUMN_SUBCHAWISE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_EXAM_TYPE + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_EXAM_DETAILS + " text not null, "
        + COLUMN_MARKS + " number not null);";
```

Comment: how can i use the SQLite Browser??